# Remove the anchor from the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm using that code to scroll to the anchor:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You can check it [here](http://www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc) - on the header menu when you click "Contato".

But every time it scrolls to the div, my URL changes to `www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc/#nameofthediv`

Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: prevent default anchor click: `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work, i've already tried.

Comment: Something else is changing the url.

Comment: In your HTML View page source you have a function called jump... I think that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it. It was another script to scroll to anchor.

Comment: Is there any script that does the same thing but scrolls to anchors on other pages?